# Setting image as Panorama Title for Panorama page in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to set the Image for Panorama Page's Title, Can we able to do this ? Actually I have done this using TitleTemplate but it is not working.. can you guide me how to set the Image as Panorama Page Title.

The Code is

```
<controls:Panorama Background="{Binding PanoramaBackground}">
  <controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="HeaderImage" Source="/Resources/header_logo.png" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate> 
</controls:Panorama>
```

But This is not working..

Thanks and Regards,

dinesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you need to actually have some data so that your template is used.
As you don't want to use any passed value in your template you can get this to work by simply setting the `Title` to an empty string.

```
<controls:Panorama Title="">
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. The problem is really, as GDM mentioned, about the top margin one needs to set.

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer of my question outside of this forum:

The proper way for draw a big image for all the panorama view in the title position is this:

```
        <controls:Panorama.Title>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,80,0,0">
                <Image x:Name="icon" Source="/Resources/Drawables/header_landscape.png" Height="163" Width="1920"/>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="my application" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-40,0,0" />-->
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:Panorama.Title>
```

Answer (score 6):

To make the header visible you can also set a top margin for your template in this way:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaHeader">
     <Grid Height="72" Margin="0,72,0,0">
          <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0" Source="/Assets/Images/header.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="72"/>
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

to make this work, remove the leading slash from the image URI. It should be:

```
<Image x:Name="HeaderImage" Source="Resources/header_logo.png" />
```