# How is/can the WP7 Office Hub panorama header markup be created?

Tags: windows-phone-7, controltemplate, panorama-control

WP7 Office hub panorama header looks like this:

[image: office hub look]

What is it?

- one solid image
- two images (one for logo, one for "microsoft Office")
- all vector elements

The answer interests me only because I know how to achieve this only in the first two cases.

Basically I need to create a TextBlock in PanoramaHeaderTemplate, that would be like this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black"><Run Text="smallBold" FontWeight="Bold"/><Run Text="Normal"></TextBlock>
```

So the resulting panorama should have a look:

[image: panorama header look]

If I use FontWeight directive in the PanoramaHeaderTemplate - it for some reason has no effect.

If I use PanoramaTitleTemplate, I get the controllable text weight, but I have a panorama header element appear for some reason, that only displays a x:Key element name of the PanoramaItem, that results in an appearance of a header I don't need at all. This happens even if I don't define the panorama header.

So which is the correct way to achieve the look on the Panorama "upper element", whether it is Title or Header, that is shown on the smallBold.Normal figure?

Comment: Are you saying that if you use the same markup outside the header template the text is rendered bold as expected, but in the header template it is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Office uses but it's irrelevant because, as a native app, it wasn't created with Silverlight.

You can create the same effect by changing the `Panorama.TitleTemplate` to contain whatever you want (TextBlocks, images, etc.). You may also have to adjust the defautl Style applied to the template to set a Height and Width for the `PanningTitleLayer`.

Comment: Thank you. By now I have figured out that the Title is the correct place to put my App name and logo. The problem with the header was that if I data bind the panorama, I, apparently, need to provide header template. If I don't, I get a Type.ToString() in the place of the header.

Answer (score 1):

It's an image, straight across the panorama. It's very simple, as the panorama view was set up to display long images to support a better scrolling feel for the user.
So i would look into using images, as it's easier to achieve, what you are trying to do, with images, rather than a background image.

Some useful related questions/articles:

- [May Help, StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592003/setting-image-as-panorama-title-for-panorama-page-in-wp7)
- [UI Concepts For Windows Phone 7](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/UI-Concepts-of-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)
- [How I made the ‘myChannel9' wp7 app](http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/mychannel9-upgraded-and-released-on-codeplex/)
- [Capturing Windows Phone 7 Panorama Images](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/07/capturing-windows-phone-7-panorama-images/)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's the correct answer (abit Keeano should learn to write more coherent. (Answer edited for clarity)

Comment: @Claus Jorgensen Thank you! Will Do better in writing more coherent.

Comment: You could start by dropping the random upper-casing of words in the middle of sentences.

Comment: @Claus - the answer, as well as the comments that were removed by moderation later, were very rood. Thank you for cleaning it up.