# WP8 Panorama Image Title

Tags: windows-phone

How do I set the Panorama App Title of a Page as an Image and not a string of text? I have added:

```
<phone:Panorama>
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="\Assets\image-logo-small.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>
        ......
```

However this sets the entire background as the image selected.

Any idea how I can replace the `<phone:Panorama Title="Text">` with an Image?

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow already has similar case in windows 7, [Setting image as Panorama Title for Panorama page in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592003/setting-image-as-panorama-title-for-panorama-page-in-wp7)

In our case try these

```
       <phone:Panorama >
        <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                   ...........
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
         ..........................
       </phone:Panorama >
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code successfully places an image within Title section of a Panorama App:

```
        <phone:Panorama>
        <phone:Panorama.Title>
            <Grid Margin="0,80,0,0">
                <Image Source="\images\MyImage.png"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="400" Height="50" />
            </Grid>
        </phone:Panorama.Title>
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for wp8:

```
<phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="/Assets/logo.png">
            </Image>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
```

Have fun!!!